# When are nodes added to elements by the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Nodes are 'automagically' added to elements by Chrome.  More experienced front end devs probably deal with this frequently.

It was surprising for me to find in Chrome that the nested div e2 `<div id="e1"><div id="e2"></div></div>` has `NodeList []` well ok, that is expected, but div e1 has
 `NodeList(3) [text, div#e2, text]`  !!

So an empty div has no child nodes while the outer of two nested divs has 3 child nodes.   I can see that text *could* be added between the divs, so the two text nodes *maybe* act as placeholders.

But I'm wondering where can I find documentation for this behaviour? What's it called anyway?

And by the same auto add logic shouldn't the inner div have a placeholder text node too??

Comment: More like how is whitespace treated in HTML

Comment: I can’t reproduce the automatic addition of text nodes with the code provided in [this Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/CostlyComplicatedSpools#script.js).

Comment: @espascarello Thanks. The docs relating to this is on MDN about Whitespace https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is how the method treats whitespace.

[childNodes: *includes all child nodes—including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes#notes)

```js
const test = elem => console.log(elem.id, elem.childNodes.length, elem.children.length);

test(document.querySelector("#test1"));
test(document.querySelector("#test2"));
test(document.querySelector("#test3"));
test(document.querySelector("#test4"));
```

```html
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"> </div>
<div id="test3"><div></div></div>
<div id="test4">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo!  I've quickly searched for the childNodes method in the EMCA spec and V8 source code (on github) and don't find anything.  Two follow up questions: What's the best way to find out what the method is doing and how do you / I avoid  these surprises??

Comment: Read the docs on MDN? Not sure how you avoid surprises when you do not know what methods do.

Comment: Yea ... MDN, EMCA nor V8 source provide documentation for this method. Seems a lot of devs are happy to fish around to determine behaviour by trial and error.  Thank you for helping me by explaining that it's white space that's being updated.